# SVG hover works on Firefox for more than one, not in Chrome, mobile

Tags: html, css, svg

I have list of buttons, the first one will work for all browsers.  But subsequent buttons, will only show hover if using Firefox.

css

```
 svg:hover #play-svg{
 fill: #CC181E;
 }
```

main body 
             
        Video

```
   <div class="play-icon" id="play2">
  <svg width="60" height="42" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> <g> <title>Video</title> <g id="icomoon-ignore"/>
  <use x="5.397434" y="-68.326835" transform="matrix(0.15880563740596462,0,0,0.1590301359360811,-34.233496722840435,-44.6817534019825) " id="icon" xlink:href="#svg_1"/> <path id="svg_4" d="m24,8.380953l0.190475,22.761904l16.952381,-11.333332l-17.142857,-11.428572z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="null" fill="#e74c3c"/> <path id="relleno" d="m24.285713,8.666666l0,22.666666l17.238094,-11.523809l-17.238094,-11.142857z" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="null" fill="#ffffff"/> </g> <defs> <svg id="svg_1" viewBox="0 0 944 1024" height="1024" width="944" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> <g id="icomoon-ignore"/> <path id="play-svg" d="m589.426025,406.15799c0,-31.289978 -25.345032,-56.652985 -56.618042,-56.652985h-265.616974c-31.27301,0 -56.618011,25.359985 -56.618011,56.652985v151.894989c0,31.290039 25.345001,56.653015 56.618011,56.653015h265.616974c31.273987,0 56.618042,-25.361023 56.618042,-56.653015v-151.894989l0,0zm-227.311035,140.032013v-142.677002l108.192017,71.339996l-108.19101,71.339996l-0.001007,-0.002991z"/> </svg> </defs> </svg>    
 </div>
```

see js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vkasmpdy/1/

Comment: Make sure your tags are properly closed and in the correct context of their other tags, else other browsers may fail on guessing which context is implied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` attributes must be unique on the page.  You will get unpredictable results if you have more than one with the same value.  Change `"play-svg"` into a class instead.

You'll also need to rename one of the `"svg_1"` ids.  You can't have two of those either.

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vkasmpdy/2/)